# javascript array consoling out and showing multi-dimensions

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a single array with 140 indexes that should look like:

```
array:[0-140]
```

//but instead it looks like:

```
array: [
     0: [0-99],
     1: [100-140]
  ]
```

Its just one array of objects, I've double and triple checked it. Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

It's not multidimensional but the console is showing it this way to make it easier for you to read. There are a lot of elements and it would be ridiculous to show, say, 2000 elements all at once if you expand it.

Comment: Oh, good. But now I feel like a real amateur. Lol, Thanks for clearing that up. What did the sailor say that had a steering wheel in his pants?

Answer (score 2):

It's just for viewing.
The array did kept as `[0-140]`
You can test on the console like `myarray[101]` and check the result